# IE9 & IE10 rem units

Tags: html, css

According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=rem), the following restraints apply to IE9 & IE10 for `rem` units:

> IE 9 & IE 10 do not support rem units when used in the font shorthand property (the entire declaration is ignored) or when used on pseudo elements.

The first caveat regarding the `font` shorthand seems to be correct, however after testing the following snippet, the second caveat seems to be a non-issue with the `::after` content `font-size` being rendered at `21px`.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        html {font-size: 14px;}
        p {font-size: 1rem;}
        p::after{content: '::after'; font-size: 1.5rem;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This seems to be the case for both IE9 and IE10. Is anyone privy to this caveat and whether there are actually any precautions required for using `rem` units in pseudo elements?

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/780274/using-rems-for-line-height-in-pseudo-element-content-collapses-the-line-height-in-ie-9-and-10) briefly implies it does not work with line-heights.

So consider testing REM thoroughly when using with pseudo elements to catch any other corner cases.

> If using rems for line-height in pseudo elements, IE 9 & 10 will collapse it to 0 if the pseudo element is to set to be block level (e.g. block, inline-block), or leave it as "normal" if it's set to be inline (e.g. inline, list-item).

Microsoft has marked this bug as 'wont fix' due to how minor it is, so it will not be resolved.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17531656)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Brandon, an appropriate quote and quick summary of its status has been included.

Comment: Thanks for updating it! :) It should be less at risk of removal now.